# Creating a counter that increments if value in column does not exist

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that has the value "Size" like below:

[image]

I'd like to increment the counter by 1, if "Size" is not entered. So desired output would look like this:

[image]

I tried using `=IF(J2="Size",1,j2 + 1)` but it outputs `#VALUE` - I've also tried using `COUNTIF()` function without any luck. This seems like it would be easy, but I cannot see how else to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the cell above when adding, I am going to assume this is put in row 2 of the column

```
=IF(J2="Size", 1,IFERROR(K1+1,1))
```

you need to refer to the cell above the formula to add 1 to the output of the formula above.

[image]

Another option is using SCAN, which will spill the results:

```
=SCAN(0,J2:J16,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="Size",1,a+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is producing **1** for all values now. I need it to increment, everytime the value "Size" does NOT show. Thanks. So every blank cell counts up from 1, until it reaches another "Size". where it resets back to 1.

Comment: @Tony then we are missing some information, as you can see from the photo I added it is in fact returning the data as it should.

Comment: Is the reference to `K1` a mistake? Shouldn't it be `J1`?

Comment: @Tony No, it is not.  `K1` should refer to the cell directly above the cell in which you put the formula.  As you can see I put the first formula in `K2` and referred to the one directly above it `K1`

Comment: I like the `scan()` option, never knew it existed! Thank you Scott!